# SQLite strange response with IN and subselect

Tags: sqlite, subquery

```sql
CREATE TABLE minitable (uid INTEGER primary key);

insert into minitable values (1);
insert into minitable values (2);
insert into minitable values (3);
insert into minitable values (4);
insert into minitable values (5);
insert into minitable values (6);

select uid
from minitable as gp
 where
  uid in (
    (select uid from minitable)
  );
```

SQLite gives only one line as the result.
I expect SQLite to give all 6 values like other database engines.
MariaDB, PostgreSQL and some other DBMSs give all values from 1 to 6 as the result.

With this,

```sql
select uid
from minitable as gp
 where
  uid in (
    1,2,3,4,5,6
  );
```

SQLite (like MariaDB and PostgreSQL) returns all values.

I tested with SQLite 3.40.1, 3.21 and 3.37.

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL Language Expressions/Subquery Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subquery_expressions) (emphasis mine):

> A SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses is a subquery. All types of
> SELECT statement, including aggregate and compound SELECT queries
> (queries with keywords like UNION or EXCEPT) are allowed as scalar
> subqueries. **The value of a subquery expression is the first row of the**
> **result from the enclosed SELECT statement....**

In your code you enclose `select uid from minitable` inside parentheses and again inside the parentheses of the list of the operator `IN`.
This way the subquery is interpreted as a single element of the list of the operator `IN` and since SQLite treats the subquery as a single value (the first row of the resultset which is the row containing only the column `uid` with a value of `1`), the full query is equivalent to:

```
select uid
from minitable as gp
where uid in (1);
```

For SQLite, your desired behavior can be achieved if you remove the parentheses around the subquery and leave only the ones of the list of the operator `IN`:

```
select uid
from minitable as gp
where uid in (select uid from minitable);
```

**UPDATE**
For [version 3.41.0+ of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/changes.html):

> The parser now ignores excess parentheses around a subquery on the
> right-hand side of an IN operator, so that SQLite now works the same
> as PostgreSQL in this regard. Formerly, SQLite treated the subquery as
> an expression with an implied "LIMIT 1".